# Give icons to icon-less toolbar options in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, icons, customization, toolbar

In Visual 2005, it was possible to give icons to any toolbar button, including those that didn't have any (such as "build only project" and "rebuild solution").

I've managed to do this up to Visual 2010, but is there any way to do this in Visual 2013? Even if it's one of the awful new icons?

Comment: What was the code or technique that you used in VS 2010?

Comment: I... *think* I used an extension that allowed editing toolbars and importing new icons, but I can't find it in the catalog nor on my current Visual 2010 install... Which would mean the toolbar icons were transferred along with the other settings, so there might be a way through editin the `.vssettings` file...

Comment: It turns out when I export the "Menu and command bar customization" settings in VS2010 or VS2005 alike, I can see it exports the custom icons as Base64 in the resulting XML file. So I can probably export my icon-less settings from VS2013, add the `CustomIcon=` attribute and re-import. I'm not on the right computer to test, but I will definitely try.

Comment: There is an extension for VS 2010 called [Commanding Image](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ff5060af-3df8-4063-b61b-19da41c66f20) that allows customizing toolbar icons.  Unfortunately there does not appear to be a version for 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Menu and command bar customization" settings exports and imports are definitely the way to go.

I did not dare to try and directly import in VS2010 an export from VS2005, but at least manually copying the `CustomIcon=` attribute from the VS2005 `.settings` to the VS2010 `.settings` does work.

Locating the right section however is tricky if you didn't rename the buttons first. If anyone tries direct export and import, please let me know.